# Should I use only one API to get all data of one screen in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and come from RestAPI. When I start to work with GraphQL, I have some confusion about whether I should split API into smaller APIs as worked with RestAPI. Assume, I have a screen that requires to display some following components:

- List of books
- List of readers.
- List of top 5 latest books.

Should I wrap all this information into one API or split them into 3 smaller APIs?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental aspect of graphQL is that there is never more nor less than a single API endpoint, which is often defined at /graphql/ or /gql/, that can only be accessed via POST. Then you define many queries (effective gets) and mutations (effective posts) that can be called at this endpoint to perform CRUD actions.

Therefore, you should define a single API with three separate queries that return the lists of books, readers, and top 5 latest books.

However, these queries *could* then be post requests to other RESTful APIs. Although, this is a question with regards to your tech-stack and the degree to which it is decomposed into microservices.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. It's very helpful but I wonder if I have other screens displaying the top 5 latest books? I assume there're 2 screens that need to display the following information:




* Screen-1: 
+ List of books
+ List of readers.
+ List of top 5 latest books.



* Screen-2:
+ List of readers.
+ List of top 5 latest books.

Should I design a single API to get data for each screen? If so, will  
 code be duplicated?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you wish to design two front-end components that will constitute these screens? If so, then you will only have a single back-end API that serves as a single-source-of-truth for your bibliographic data that can be called by both components in the form of an HTTP request. In this way, there is no duplication.